# Can I restart an iPython cluster from a notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython-parallel

I'm just wondering if there is some python code or magics I can execute that will restart the ipython cluster. It seems like every time I change my code, it needs to be restarted.

Comment: I'd wonder if there is a notebook extension that could do this but I'd have doubts about code running inside the notebook that restarts it, could result in an infinite loop of running-restarting.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea, seems too "hacky" for production:

Setup the `Client` and define a simple function for testing.

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
c = ipp.Client()
dv = c[:]

# simple function
@dv.remote(block=True)
def getpid():
    import os
    return os.getpid()

getpid()
[1994, 1995, 1998, 2001]
```

Define a function to restart the cluster. [`shutdown`](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/ipyparallel.html#ipyparallel.Client.shutdown) with `targets='all'` and `hub=True` should kill the entire cluster.  Then start a new cluster with `!` or [%sx](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-sx) magic command.

```
import time
def restart_ipcluster(client):
    client.shutdown(targets='all', hub=True)
    time.sleep(5) # give the cluster a few seconds to shutdown

    # include other args as necessary
    !ipcluster start -n4 --daemonize
    time.sleep(60) # give cluster ~min to start

    return ipp.Client() # with keyword args as necessary
```

One drawback to this approach is that the DirectView needs to be re-assigned and any function decorated with `dv.remote` or `dv.parallel` needs to be re-executed.

```
c = restart_ipcluster(c)    
dv = c[:]

@dv.remote(block=True)
def getpid():
    import os
    return os.getpid()

getpid()
[3620, 3621, 3624, 3627]
```

Reading the source for  ipyparallel `Client`, the `shutdown` method mentioned above has a keyword argument, `restart=False` , but it's currently not implemented.  Maybe the devs are working on a reliable method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll give it a go. Is there a reason why, by design, the main notebook has no process control?

Answer (score 0):

One can start/stop an IPython cluster using the class [`Cluster`](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/ipyparallel.html#classes).

> Class representing an IPP cluster.
> i.e. one controller and one or more groups of engines.
> Can start/stop/monitor/poll cluster resources.
> All async methods can be called synchronously with a `_sync` suffix, e.g. `cluster.start_cluster_sync()`

Here's a demo:

**Start the cluster and check if it's running**

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
cluster = ipp.Cluster(n=4)
# start cluster asyncronously (or cluster.start_cluster_sync() without await)
await cluster.start_cluster()

# Using existing profile dir: '/Users/X/.ipython/profile_default'
# Starting 4 engines with <class 'ipyparallel.cluster.launcher.LocalEngineSetLauncher'>

# <Cluster(cluster_id='1648978529-rzr8', profile='default', controller=<running>, engine_sets=['1648978530'])>

rc = ipp.Client(cluster_id='1648978529-rzr8')

cluster._is_running()
# True
```

This can be also seen in the Clusters tab of the Jupyter notebook:
[image: one cluster running - Jupyter notebook - ipyparallel]

**Stop the cluster**

```
# stop cluster syncronously
cluster.stop_cluster_sync()

cluster._is_running()
# False
```

**Restart the cluster**

```
# start cluster syncronously
cluster.start_cluster_sync()

cluster._is_running()
# True
```

**Use cluster as a context manager**

A cluster can be also used as a context manager using a with-statement (https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Cluster%20API.html#Cluster-as-a-context-manager):

```
import os
with ipp.Cluster(n=4) as rc:
    engine_pids = rc[:].apply_async(os.getpid).get_dict()
engine_pids
```

This way the cluster will only exist for the duration of the computation.

See also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71721629/2314737).