# ipyparallel Exception: "You have attempted to connect to an IPython Cluster but no Controller could be found"

Tags: python, json, ipython, ipython-parallel

I've just started using ipyparallel, I'm using VS2017 and importing it as;

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
```

And then attempting to start it using;

```
def main():
    rc = ipp.Client()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

in the python window I get the message: "Waiting for connection file: ~.ipython\profile_default\security\ipcontroller-client.json"

It hangs on the rc = ip.Client() line and gives the exception in the question. There doesn't appear to be any file called profile_default at that location, let alone a json file.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs if no cluster is running.

```
import ipyparallel as ipp
rc = ipp.Client()
```

Here's the error message:

> Waiting for connection file:
> ~/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json
>
> ---
>
> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 rc = ipp.Client()
> OSError: Connection file '~/.ipython/profile_default/security/ipcontroller-client.json' not found.
> You have attempted to connect to an IPython Cluster but no Controller could be found.
> Please double-check your configuration and ensure that a cluster is running.

Here's a function to show which clusters are running:

```
def show_clusters():
    clusters = ipp.ClusterManager().load_clusters() 
    print("{:15} {:^10} {}".format("cluster_id", "state", "cluster_file")) 
    for c in clusters:
        cd = clusters[c].to_dict()
        cluster_id = cd['cluster']['cluster_id']
        controller_state = cd['controller']['state']['state']
        cluster_file = getattr(clusters[c], '_trait_values')['cluster_file']
        print("{:15} {:^10} {}".format(cluster_id, controller_state, cluster_file))
```

In this case there were no clusters running.

```
show_clusters()
# cluster_id        state    cluster_file
```

In Jupyter notebooks one can enable a tab for clusters (`ipcluster nbextension enable`). This is how it looks when no cluster is running:

[image: no running cluster]

Start a cluster

```
cluster = ipp.Cluster(n=4)
await cluster.start_cluster() # or cluster.start_cluster_sync() without await
# Using existing profile dir: '/Users/X/.ipython/profile_default'
# Starting 4 engines with <class 'ipyparallel.cluster.launcher.LocalEngineSetLauncher'>

show_clusters()
# cluster_id        state    cluster_file
# 1648935811-e7r2  running /Users/X/.ipython/profile_default/security/cluster-1648935811-e7r2.json
```

Now you can define a client using the cluster id:

```
rc = ipp.Client(cluster_id='1648935811-e7r2')
```

This is how the Jupyter notebook clusters tab looks after starting a cluster:

[image: IPython cluster]

If you start the default cluster from the Jupyter notebook tab (not sure how to do this on the command-line), the command `rc = ipp.Client()` will also work without a cluster id.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a dumb newbie question. The answer is in the docs. The .json files are created when you first use ipcluster in powershell. I was looking for profile_default in anaconda but its in .ipython/ in Users.